# fadeTo breaks smooth scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling, fadeto

I'm using this snippet I found online to smooth scroll:

```
    $( "a[href*='#']" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var href = event.target.href; 
    href = href.slice( href.indexOf( "#" ), href.length );
    $( "body" ).animate( {
       scrollTop: $( href ).get( 0 ).offsetTop
    }, 1000 );
    } );
```

It works just fine but it breaks when it comes across an image that is fading in. I have some images set to fadeTo from opacity 0 to 1 and when the scroll animation comes across those images it stops dead in it's tracks. In other words, the smooth scroll always stops at my first div because there are images fading in that stop the scroll so the scroll animation never takes the user to their desired destination.

How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

The janky-ness you're seeing is due to the extra rendering required to update the opacity of the images during the scroll, versus the scroll alone.

I'd suggest your best bet would be to disable the fade whilst the scroll is occurring.

To do this you could either set opacity to 1 for all images before calling `animate()`, or to prevent the fade from occurring until after the animation is complete, however the method to do this would depend on the code/framework used for the image fade.

Comment: My image fade code is just fadeTo 0 on load and fadeTo 1 on scroll if the div or element is visible. I've been trying to figure out how to best stop the animation until the scroll is done but nothing yet. Any tips?

Comment: Assuming you're not using a library, you can add in a boolean to represent whether fading is enabled, and set it to false when you begin to scroll and true when the scroll is complete.  Then in your fade logic, disable the fade if the value is set. Once the scroll is complete, have a method which will fade in any images currently visible.
If you are using a library to manage the fade it may have function available to disable and re-enable the functionality.

Comment: I fixed it. My fadeTo was being disrupted by a display:none I forgot to remove, I was low on sleep. Thanks for trying to help.